# Apache mod_rewrite folder to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

**domain.com/folder/index.php/var1/var2/etc/** should redirect to **folder.domain.com/var1/var2/etc/** i.e. keeping the parameters intact but redirecting and stripping the index.php

Folder structure is as follows

Webroot
   .htaccess
   folder
      index.php

Whilst I can get domain.com/folder/... to redirect to folder.domain.com/... with the following

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/(.*)$  
RewriteRule .* http://folder.domain.com/%1 [R]
```

When I attempt to strip the index.php with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

It all starts to go wrong. The URL schema that I want works fine (folder.domain.com) but it is also still available at the folder URL (domain.com/folder/index.php) I've also tried placing some and all of the .htaccess in the folder - what am I missing?

Adding a few examples of the behaviour I'm trying to implement:

```
domain.com/folder/index.php/var1/var2 = folder.domain.com/var1/var2  
folder.domain.com/index.php/var1/var2 = folder.domain.com/var1/var
```

Comment: Clarification: remove the index.php from the visible URL but continue to direct the request to it for execution.

Answer (score 0):

I can make many suggestions for you, but I think this is the best one for now (note: **untested**, I'm not at a PC right now):

```
RewriteCond%{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/
RewriteRule ^folder/index.php/(.*)$ http://folder.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That should redirect you to the domain, and strip the `index.php`.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work (and I added a missing space after the RewriteCond) So a few examples of input and output URLS to better illustrate where I'm getting tangled up: 

`domain.com/folder/index.php/var1/var2 = folder.domain.com/var1/var2  

folder.domain.com/index.php/var1/var2 = folder.domain.com/var1/var`

Comment: What is the difference between your two examples. I can only see that the second one has a `var`, instead of a `var2`. Where does the `var` come from?

Comment: Sorry thats just my notation to say that anything could go there, kind of a wildcard if you will. (and a typo on my part, missed the 2)